# Scraping Trulia tables

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm looking for the data in the table

http://www.trulia.com/school-district/CA-San_Francisco_County/San_Francisco_Unified/

When a search the Xpath of the first element "Yu(alice Fong) Elementary School" I get this:

```
//*[@id="elementary_tab_content"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a
```

When I look for:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="elementary_tab_content"]/table').extract()
```

I get a response, not yet what I need

When I try:

```
response.xpath('//*@id="elementary_tab_content"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a').extract()
```

I get nothing, in fact the answer is empty after I add '/tbody'

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="elementary_tab_content"]/table/tbody').extract()
```

How can I extract the data of this table with scrapy?

Comment: To improve the clarity of your question, you should specify what exactly you are trying to extract. Do you need to use XPath or is this what you are most comfortable with. Also be sure to read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, that contains some great information about  asking good questions on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use something like:

```
'//*[@id="elementary_tab_content"]/table//tr'
```

to get the rows.

`tbody` is usually added by the browser for tables, so not really inside the response body.